# how to use wordpress's uploader in my plugin's custom post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins, uploader

we are trying to create a portfolio plugin and we need wordpress's inbuilt uploader to let plugin users upload portfolio images but I could not find the proper way to implement.

Comment: yes, in admin pages in our custom portfolio menu.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  


 var uploadID = '';
  jQuery('.uploadbtn').click(function() {
   uploadID = jQuery(this).prev('input');
   //alert(uploadID);
   tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
   set_send(uploadID);
   return false;
  }); 
 function set_send(uploadID) {
  window.send_to_editor = function(html) {   
   imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
   uploadID.val(imgurl);
   tb_remove();
  };
 }
});

Comment: how to create a dynamic link in custom plugin? what is the function of the creating dynamic link?